# MKMapView with annotations works fine in old version of App store app and in simulator but now doesn't work on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, mkmapview

I have an app in the app store which I'm maintaining. It has an MKMapView which you can add annotations to and snapshot etc. This worked perfectly in the old version of the app, but after my most recent submission, no longer works on my device after the update from the app store (the map view shows up but you can't add pins etc, although the very same build could on the simulator). When I run that build on the simulator everything works fine and still does.

I'm not going to bother to add code just yet because it's pretty obvious that's not the issue, I didn't change any of it. Also when I run it on the device the breakpoints indicate it is setting annotations.

This is truly bizarre and I'm wondering if anyone has ever had a similar issue.

Thank you for the help!

//July 21

EDIT: The pins are still there, the map and location are getting set up fine but the annotations don't show up on the screen after a day or so and when I perform a search request or try to change the map type etc. nothing works, although breakpoints show the map and annotations still exist.

Code to set up map view, always gets called and sets up region without a problem.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[LocationManagerController sharedInstance];

}



- (void)setUpMapView {

[[LocationManagerController sharedInstance]getCurrentLocationWithCompletion:^(CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation, BOOL success) {

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 75)];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
    self.currentMapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;

    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;

    mapRegion.center = currentLocation;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.025;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.025;

    [self.mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated:YES]; 

    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.mapView]; 

}];

UITapGestureRecognizer *pressRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapPressGesture:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pressRecognizer];


}
```

The delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {


self.pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinAnnotation"];

self.pinAnnotation.pinTintColor = self.pinTintColor;

self.pinAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;

return self.pinAnnotation;

}
```

Handling the tap gesture

```
- (void)handleTapPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {


CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

MapAnnotation *dropPin = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithLocation:locCoord];

NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", dropPin.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", dropPin.coordinate.longitude];

[[LocationController sharedInstance] addLocationWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:dropPin reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pin %lu",(unsigned long)self.arrayOfPins.count]];
self.arrayOfPins = [self.arrayOfPins arrayByAddingObject:pin];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:dropPin];
[self playClongSound];

}
```

Pop error alert if there's no internet (In location manager file)

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error: Please check your internet connection" message:error.localizedDescription preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]rootViewController]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]; 

[alertController addAction:action];

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] rootViewController]presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: What OS did the first version of the App get released for? IE: What was the target OS version?

Comment: I don't see anything under the OS deployment targets but the iOS one is for 8.3 in the build settings. I tried change that around a bit but to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a link to the Appstore app? I'll download it from the appstore on my device(s) and see if it works.

Comment: Here you go... https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snapption/id987532848?mt=8

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/oKvEeC5.jpg seems to be working. Icons are fairly large but it works..

Comment: Is that version 3.4? That's good news if it works for you, thanks for checking it out. Not sure why it won't work on my device, I'm connected to the internet and all.

Comment: I installed it from the Appstore so it's the latest version that you have submitted. That device is an iPhone 6s - 9.3. Also tested on iPhone 6s - 10.0 beta; works on both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117497/discussion-between-echizzle-and-brandon).

Comment: Alright well after a couple of times deleting it off my phone and re downloading it from the app store it now works. What was wrong? I have no idea...

Comment: And now it's happening again, I'm using the app store version, it was working fine earlier and yesterday, I have internet and all... right now the Map View is not responsive yet again. I have no idea what on earth is going on... this is beyond bizarre

Comment: It means you have undefined behaviour going on. If you could share the code, I can help further. If not, I can't tell you off the top of my head what might be wrong. Without any code, it's hard to tell what might be happening.

Comment: Indeed, I edited my question above. From what I gather it works for about a day then the map view stops showing the annotations. I bet if you try now you might get the same problem. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm guessing it could have something to do with the didUpdateUserLocation or regionDidChangeAnimated delegate methods? I'm not implementing either of those but maybe that's the problem. This is the first version in which I've tracked the User's location.